# Collision detection algorithm in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a small game, consisting of a labyrinth, a player character and a set number of enemies. Both the PC and the enemies belong to a given class, and they update their movement every several milliseconds according to a criteria specified by me. (All of these restrictions are part of the assignment). Now, I am trying to write a criteria so that neither the enemies nor the PC will move to a square occupied by a labyrinth wall. For this, I used the following method (all of this within the Game class I am making):

```
def isNotWall(self,x,y):

        self.wallXI = 0
        self.wallXF = 0
        self.wallYI = 0
        self.wallYF = 0
        for wall in self.wallList:
            self.wallXI = wall[0]*self.grid + 1
            self.wallXF = (wall[0]+1)*self.grid
            self.wallYI = wall[1]*self.grid + 1
            self.wallYF = (wall[1]+1)*self.grid
            if self.wallXI < x < self.wallXF and self.wallYI < y < self.wallYF:
                return False


        return True
```

Where wallList is a list containing the x and y coordinates for every wall in array coordinates, and grid is the size of each grid square (32 pixels, in this case).

Now, for an example of how I implemented this:

```
if snake[1] > self.heroe_x:
            if self.isNotWall(snake[1] - 30,snake[2]):
                snake[1] = snake[1] - 30 * segundos
```

Where snake[1] is the x-coordinate in pixels, snake[2] is y, and segundos is how many milliseconds have passed, so that the enemy will move the appropriate number of pixels.

According to this, the snake (and the character) should not move in a certain direction if their location at the end of the movement is occupied by a wall. However, this only works partially, the behaviour is erratic, some walls only work in one direction, and often the characters get stuck inside walls or stopped cold for no reason.

Any help with fixing these flaws would be appreciated. I realize this question isn't very concise, but due to my inexperience with the language, I could not think of a way to make the question more specific, and no previous answers have helped me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

if you only check the final position, wouldn't the snake hit a wall if it's in the way.
Say the wall is only 15 square from the snake?

Also, the snake is moving 30*segundos but you are only checking if there is a wall 30 square away

```
if snake[1] > self.heroe_x:
    next_position_x = snake[1] - (30 * segundos)
    if self.isNotWall(next_position_x,snake[2]):
        snake[1] = next_position_x
```

If I were you, I would implement a real path finding algorithm and make the walls passing cost infinite so that it will never cross one.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding

Also check this library

http://lib2dp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I see the problems that you point out, but bear in mind I cannot use external libraries (it's for an assignment). Do you have any suggestions to implement isNotWall for every pixel in the range between the current position and the one at arrival? My attempts so far haven't worked.

Comment: You could check every square on the way. Implementing a path finder should not be very hard. A* (A star) is a very convenient and not so hard algorithm to implement.

Comment: While I appreciate the suggestions, I'm afraid that implementing pathfinding algorithms is beyond the complexity of this assignment. That said, I isolated the source of the problem, which is that the program considers the coordinates of the character as a single point x, y in pixels. I am now trying to come up with a way to implement a method so that a character's position is defined by a square of side self.grid, allowing for some overlap with the walls.